# DBeaver connection via SSH tunnel

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, mariadb, ssh-tunnel, dbeaver

Using DBeaver, I'm trying to connect to my AWS ec2 instance where I've installed a MariaDB database.

I've created a new connection as:

- Connection: AWS / Maria DB
- Server Host: localhost (because I'm using ssh to connect)
- Database, Username and Password: the right ones
- Port: 3306

SSH tunnel on the connection:

- Use SSH Tunnel: checked
- Host/IP, Port and User: as suggested by the AWS documentation
- Auth: Public Key
- Private key: file .pem (the one I'm also using to connect via ssh from command line)

The connection works great at the beginning.
After some minutes of inactivity if I open a table the connection stucks and I need to invalidate/reconnect to fetch the data. This process sometimes is done by DBeaver, after 15 seconds of not fetching anything, but sometimes even if I wait 2 minutes it keeps running but fetching nothing.

Is there something I'm missing in my configuration? Or some configuration on the server maybe.. I don't know..

Have you ever had this problem?

Comment: Please use hostname instead of public ip to connect. As public IP keeps changing in AWS ec2.

Comment: @ROHITKHURANA Yes, as ssh host I'm using the hostname: ###.compute.amazonaws.com

Answer (score 3):

config using the pem key in ssh  tunnel

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here I had the same situation. Previous versions of `DBeaver` used to keep the connection longer (I don't remember precisely which version), in the order of hours.

I solved this issue by using a VPN or a SSH port forwarding from my machine. So, it is the same configuration as yours with localhost, but the tunnel is done outside `DBeaver`.